# Laravel 8 Authentication: auth::attemp always return false

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 and trying to authenticate an user (sign in)

My model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
class AccountModel extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Authenticatable;
    protected $table='Accounts';
    protected $primaryKey= 'Username';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['Username','Password','RoleID','RegisteredAt','Status','updated_at','created_at'];
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password; 
    }
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->Username; 
    }
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token'
    ];        
}
```

My controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Models\AccountModel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Cookie;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LogInController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        return view('Admin.LogIn');
    }
    public function Username()
    {
        return 'Username';
    }
    function loginaction($usn,$pw)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'Username'=>$usn,
            'password'=>$pw,
        ];
            if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
                $credentials->cookie()->regenerate();
                return redirect()->intended('/Admin/Home');
            }
            else
                return $credentials;
    }
```

config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'admin',
        'passwords' => 'admin',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admin',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\AccountModel::class,
        ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admin',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],


    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Migartion

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAccountsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('Username');
            $table->string('Password');
            $table->int('RoleID');
            $table->timestamp('RegisteredAt');
            $table->string('Status');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('Accounts');
    }
}
```

Blade (Ajax worked, data sent)

```
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" id="typeusername" data-validate="Nhập tên đăng nhập">
            <input class="input100" id="usn" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="‍"></span>
            <p class="error-login" style="color:red;font-size:13px;display:none;"> ! Chưa nhập tên đăng nhập </p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" id="typepassword" data-validate="Nhập mật khẩu">
            <input class="input100" id="psw" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder=""></span>
            <p class="error-login" style="color:red;font-size:13px;display:none;"> ! Chưa nhập mật khẩu </p>
        </div>
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
            <button class="login100-form-btn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
        </div>
<script>
    function login()
    {
        var usn = $("#usn").val();
        var pass = $("#psw").val();
         $.get("{{route('bLogIn')}}/" + usn +"/" + pass , function (res) {
                if (res =='Fail')
                { 
                    $(".alerterror").css("display", "block");
                } 
                else
                    window.location.href = "{{route('bHome')}}";
            });
    }
</script>
```

I'm using Ajax to send data from view to controller. It sent, the controller have it, my code also use Where clause to check the right table -  'Accounts' i save in my MySQL database . Username and password exist but attemp still return false.

Can Anyone Tell Me Why It Cant Run Successfully?

Comment: screen your codes in migration and blade file!

Comment: done ............, dont mind blade file,just  check in my controller. ajax worked

Comment: Are you including the CSRF token in the ajax Request ?
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: shouldn't your `getAuthIdentifierName` be a string like `'Username'` instead of `$this->Username`

Comment: "{{route('bLogIn')}}" is this route  correct and why you don't send username and password  in post body ? if can you screen your route file too.

Comment: Again, my ajax worked and My controller get Data ( username, password). So please stop asking about my blade view

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using different field name for password .By default its small letter `password` but in your case first letter is capital `Password` so you can do define an accessor like below

```
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->Password;
}
```

**Updated**
I have tested and solved using following.
Your `Account model` should implement following methods

```
 public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return $this->Username;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password; 
    }
```

and
in your controller you should use

```
 $credentials = [
            'Username'=>"test",
            'password'=>"admin@123",
        ];
```

while passing password field it should be lower case then your model method will convert it to according to model class
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

Updated Answer

**AccountModel**

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class AccountModel extends   Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table='accounts';
    protected $primaryKey= 'Username';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['Username','Password','RoleID','RegisteredAt','Status','updated_at','created_at'];
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token'
    ];
  //  protected $guard = 'admin';


    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->Username;
    }
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return $this->Username;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password; // case sensitive
    }

}
```

In Controller

```
 $credentials = [
            'Username'=>"test",
            'Password'=>"admin@123",
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
          //  $credentials->cookie()->regenerate();
           dd(auth()->user());
        }
        else
            return $credentials;
```

Comment: No. I’m use “Password” everywhere so i think it’s not problem. Even in Illuminate/Auth/Authenticatable.php and EloquentUserProvider

Comment: @MikeLinh,you are using default auth scaffolding right.

Comment: No’ i’m not use it

Comment: @MikeLinh.i will check again in your question

Comment: @MikeLinh.Updated Answer

Comment: @MikeLinh.it should work . i have tested it.can you show your updated login and model

Comment: login controller and model class

Comment: oh, just do exactly like u advised

Comment: @MikeLinh.i have created  in local and it works fine for me after change password to lowercase in credential array.so i wanted to see updated controller

Comment: @MikeLinh.updated my code for more clarity what i did

Comment: @MikeLinh.I have verifed again and it works fine.now only thing to your scenario is by hardcoding username and password in controller once so you can verify

Comment: oh. i fixed it. because in my EloquentUserProvider, password is hashed before checked so it's required at least 60 character. i think it's unnecessary so i changed to compare 2 strings function.Anyway, i'm really appericiate with your help, it's my first question on SO

Comment: @MikeLinh.Glad that you resolved your issue.if my anwser helped then mark answer as accepted .

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it. because in my EloquentUserProvider, password is hashed before checked so it's required at least 60 character. i think it's unnecessary so i changed to compare 2 strings function